# How to fix this - Event Log In Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Now to Build APK File but don't pass. In event show message

```
Internal error when trying to read zip file C:\Users\rouge\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-28.0.0.aar\9e52911133c1feedaf8fb7d084c5b106\jars\classes.jar'.
```

Please tell me how to fix this problem with me.

Comment: Have you tried options like Invalidate Cache and Restart and Clean Code ?

Comment: I've tried it. But it still displays such information.